# laravel how to make guzzle returning variable

Tags: laravel-5, goutte, guzzle6, guzzle

I am scrapping a website for news (yes we got permission) however because of the website layout I want to scrape these details:

-title
-description
-date published
-link to article

I know how to scrape all of that data together or how to get specific field like title.

I want to retrieve them seperately because they are going to a database:

database has a same structure

-id
-title
-description
etc

so therefore if I retrieve title I want it to go to title in database, however description needs to match that title so I can later on output them in laravel such as

```
@foreach
$news->title
$news->description
```

My code so far:

```
function oldham_chronicle(){
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.oldham-chronicle.co.uk/news-features');
    $crawler->filter('div[id=content]>div>h3')->parents()->each(function ($node) {
        $test = "<div class='news'>" . $node->text() . "<br>" . "<br>";
        return $test;
    });
    $crawler->filter('div[id=content]>div>p')->parents()->each(function ($node) {
        $test2 = "<div class='p'>" . $node->text() . "<br>" . "<br>";
        return $test2;
    });
return view('chronicle');
```

Help! I am stuck